# How to loop through anchor links using a previous and next button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a mobile navigation with the main function of looping through a set of anchor links in the page using a previous and next button.

This is what the logic I could think of so far:

```
// Anchor links are set, these are the names
const anchors = ['year-1800s', 'year-1850s', 'year-1900s', 'year-1970s'];
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.sidebar-mobile-btn-next');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.sidebar-mobile-btn-prev');

function navNext() {
}

function navPrev() {
}

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', navNext());
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', navPrev());
```

Edit: I am using Bootstrap scrollspy, so there will be an 'active' class if one of the anchor links section is on the viewport. How do I also detect which anchors to go to based on the 'active' class?

Comment: `nextBtn.addEventListener('click', navNext());` will have to be `nextBtn.addEventListener('click', navNext);` unless `navNext` is supposed to return a function.

Comment: Store index of anchor in variable and on click on buttons change the index.

Comment: @Mohammad thanks, but how do I loop through the anchors? And how do I check if the current anchor is active? ie. viewport is showing #1800s section

Comment: So share your html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

```js
const anchors = ['year-1800s', 'year-1850s', 'year-1900s', 'year-1970s'];
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.sidebar-mobile-btn-next');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.sidebar-mobile-btn-prev');

let index = 0;

function navNext(e) {
  index = (index === anchors.length - 1) ? 0 : ++index;
  e.target.href = `#${anchors[index]}`;
  console.log(e.target.href, index);
}

function navPrev(e) {
  index = (index === 0) ? anchors.length-1 : --index;
  e.target.href = `#${anchors[index]}`;
  console.log(e.target.href, index);
}

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', navNext);
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', navPrev);
```

```html
<a class="sidebar-mobile-btn-prev" href="#">Prev</a>
|
<a class="sidebar-mobile-btn-next" href="#">Next</a>
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

```
Below is a solution I created for the same page anchors.
Can be modified to work accordingly and is pretty fast.

<script>
function page() {
var Pnum = parseFloat(document.getElementById("MyNumber").value);

window.location.href="#"+Pnum;

}
</script>

Page: <em  style="font-size:150%;background-color:green;border-radius:4px;position:relative;right:6px;">

<b title="Subtract 1 &#10; Here..." onclick="if (MyNumber.value>1){MyNumber.value=(parseInt(MyNumber.value))-1};page()" style="cursor:pointer"><</b>

<input onchange="page();" style="position:relative;top:-2px;right:1px;width:22px;height:20px;" value="1" alt="1" type="text" id="MyNumber" name="MyNumber" maxlength="2" size="2" min="1" max="99" >

<b title="Add 1 &#10; Here..." onclick="if (MyNumber.value<35){MyNumber.value=(parseInt(MyNumber.value))+1};page()" style="position:relative;right:4px;cursor:pointer">></b>

</em>
<b title="Reset to Current MyNumber" style="position:relative;top:-2px;right:14px;cursor:pointer;background-color:red;" onclick="MyNumber.value=MyNumber.alt;MyNumber.focus();page();return false">&times;</b>&nbsp;
&nbsp;



<!--P1 Start --> <a name="1"></a>

More content Here...


<!--P2 Start --> <a name="2"></a>

More content Here...

<!--P3 Start --> <a name="3"></a>

More content Here...
```

Comment: Please post code that relates to the shared code in the example

Comment: The prior code works for a 35 page site(MyNumber.value<35).
That can be modified as needed. 
Of course, the pages should be added where states (More content Here...).
Provided this solution because can be accommodated for the original inquire and also other sites.
I hope this helps